# codepen css and js code not accessible from broswer or external url

Tags: javascript, css, cdn, codepen

I created a pen in `codepen.io` a few years back and I used to be able to access the raw js and css file from browser by adding the file extension on top of the url of the pen. I found these files are not accessible anymore. May I know is it some usage change recently in codepen.io?

```
my pen:  [https://codepen.io/zh1611/pen/bjaEKJ][1]
[https://codepen.io/zh1611/pen/bjaEKJ.css][2] - return empty page with Pen Not Found
[https://codepen.io/zh1611/pen/bjaEKJ.js][3] - return empty page Pen Not Found
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/zh1611/pen/bjaEKJ by going to this link I can see your code in the editor of codepen

Comment: check in view option, right next to settings

Comment: i wonder how come https://codepen.io/zh1611/pen/bjaEKJ.css is not accessible?

Answer (score 2):

I asked this question to CodePen support. And they replied:

> Access to the raw HTML, CSS, or JS file from a Pen is a perk of a CodePen PRO subscription.
>
> Raw files on free accounts can only be [referenced by other Pens](https://blog.codepen.io/documentation/es-modules-on-codepen/#importing-pens).